# Write to PDF using PHP from android device

Tags: php, android

I am trying to write to a pdf file on php server. I have sent variables to the server, create the pdf document, then have my phone download the document to view on device. The variables seem not to write on the php file. I have my code below

```
 public void postData() {
    try {
    Calculate calc = new Calculate();

    HttpClient mClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("myurl.com/pdf.php");

    HttpPost mpost = new HttpPost(sb.toString());

            String value = "1234";

    List nameValuepairs = new ArrayList(1);

    nameValuepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",value));



    mpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuepairs));


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    Log.w(" error ", e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.w(" error ", e.toString());
    }
}
```

And my php code to write the variable "value" onto the pdf document:

```
//code to reverse the string
if($_POST[] != null) {
$reversed = strrev($_POST["value"]);

$this->SetFont('Arial','u',50);

$this->Text(52,68,$reversed);

}
```

I am just trying to write the variable in a random spot, but the if statement is always null and I do not know why. Thanks. Sorry if it is a little sloppy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if($_POST[] != null) {
```

Try:

```
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'value' ] ) && ! empty( $_POST[ 'value' ] ) ) {
```

Comment: Then it's likely not working for a different reason than posed in your question. Doing a `vardump( $_POST )` or `echo json_encode( $_POST )` will help you see what you're sending.

Comment: Never mind thanks it worked! There was a picture on top of it covering it up. Although when I send something like 2,345.58 it flips it and prints it like 85.543,2. Any suggestions?

Comment: ^ that's nuts. never heard of something like that. when you say "it flips it," what is the "it"?

Comment: Yeah, it just flipped the string. So if I sent "Hello", it prints"oellH". I just went with it and made a method to flip all the strings before so it sends "oellH" and flips it back to "Hello". Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Check on the Android side of things. I don't know of any non-explicit PHP code that would do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

In the `if` statement you haven't specified a key in the $_POST array. Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST["value"]) 
{
  $reversed = strrev($_POST["value"]);

  $this->SetFont('Arial','u',50);

  $this->Text(52,68,$reversed);
}
```